# WARNING:base_connection:Unknown state on disconnect: 0 Pika/Celery/Rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to run the hello world version of using celery/rabbitmq (from rabbitmq site).

When I run `python send.py` it outputs this and throws an error:

```
python send.py
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!'
WARNING:pika.adapters.base_connection:Unknown state on disconnect: 0
WARNING:pika.adapters.base_connection:Unknown state on disconnect: 0
```

Here is my `send.py` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='xx.xxx.xx.xxx'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'"
connection.close()
```

here is `receive.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='xx.xxx.xx.xxx'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

print ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print " [x] Received %r" % (body,)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

**EDIT (FIX):**
To not receive this warning of `WARNING:pika.adapters.base_connection:Unknown state on disconnect: 0`

Remove the `connection.close()` used in either send.py or receive.py files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how celery is coming into play here, since you're just doing the RabbitMQ "Hello, world" tutorial, which has nothing to do with celery. But I believe those warnings are actually just caused by a bug in pika. It's not anything you're doing wrong with your example. See the bug report here: https://github.com/pika/pika/pull/346

Note that they're just warnings; they're being printed when connection.close() is called, and won't affect the behavior of the program at all.

Comment: if I run send.py, then run receive.py - it outputs:  [x] Received 'Hello World!' but in the window that is running the celery workers - i dont see anything about " [x] Received 'Hello World!'" does this mean the process went through?

Comment: What are you expecting the celery workers to do here? The code you provided is pure RabbitMQ; it doesn't use celery at all. I wouldn't expect your celery workers to receive a message you published to a regular RabbitMQ queue.

Comment: Well the workers will say "Running on" in Terminal, but i wondered when msgs were processed by celery workers if they would output on the terminal as well e.g. "Processed X task" ?